# Select rows with specific condition from other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, select, rows

I have dataframe `df` which has one column:

```
colors
red
blue
green
black
pink
```

And another dataframe `df1` which has many columns (~300 columns):

```
colorName col1 col2 ... colN
pink 1 0 1 ... 0
white 0 1 1 ... 1
blue 1 0 0 ... 0
yellow 0 0 0 ... 0
```

What I need is to return the rows of `df` in which it exists in `df1.colorName` and have at least value 1 in any of the columns (col1 ... colN)

So, from the above; the output should be:

```
blue
pink
```

I'm starting with this but I'm sure it needs an additional condition for (checking have at least value 1 in any of the columns (col1 ... colN))

`newDF = df[df.colors.isin(df1.colorName) && ]`

Correct me if I'm wrong and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with select columns by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) - all columns without first with [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) for at least one `True` per rows and [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for column `colorName` first and pass it to filtering by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
c = df1.loc[df1.iloc[:, 1:].any(axis=1), 'colorName']
#alternative
#c = df1.loc[df1.drop('colorName', axis=1).any(axis=1), 'colorName']
newDF = df[df. colors.isin(c)]
print (newDF)
  colors
1   blue
4   pink
```

**Detail**:

```
print (c)
0     pink
1    white
2     blue
Name: colorName, dtype: object
```